# SharePoint List.getListItems WebService to return sub folder contents, recursively

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am calling the lists.asmx webservice from [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).
The following soap call does not return files from list sub folders. It returns folder1,folder2 and file1.pdf

```
Shared Documents
  folder1
     file2.docx
     file3.pdf
  folder2
     sub-folder1
        file5.pdf
     file4.pdf
  file1.pdf
```

SOAP call

```
POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:GetListItems>
         <soap1:listName>Shared Documents</soap1:listName>
       <queryOptions> 
        <QueryOptions> 
           <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
           <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
           <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>               
        </QueryOptions>
      </queryOptions> 
      </soap1:GetListItems>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any clues on how to get files from folder1, folder3 and sub-folder1 included in the result?.
If Lists web service cannot do it, is there an alternative service/method?

**Additional Information:**
There is another webservice, `SiteData (_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx)`. It has a similar method ( getListItems) and returns all files with just the list name and  no additional parameters.The issue is I could not figure out how/where to specify the Paging parameter, as there is NO queryOptions input element like in the Lists webservice.

```
 <soap1:strListName>?</soap1:strListName>
 <soap1:strQuery>?</soap1:strQuery>
 <soap1:strViewFields>?</soap1:strViewFields>
 <soap1:uRowLimit>?</soap1:uRowLimit>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible to get the list contents recursively, using `<ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>` elment. 
There is a `silly` mistake in my soap envelope. The queryOptions element has no namespace. I fixed in the following text.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:GetListItems>
         <soap1:listName>Shared Documents</soap1:listName>
       <**soap1:**queryOptions> 
        <QueryOptions> 
           <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
           <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
           <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>               
        </QueryOptions>
      </**soap1:**queryOptions> 
      </soap1:GetListItems>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Btw, there is a great tool, [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to build SharePoint CAML. I wish I found that a few weeks ago.

Comment: i am getting Response code: 400, Response message: Bad Request, when I add **soap1:** lines .. am i missing something ?

Comment: i tried with same request for getting all the folders and files inside given list. But it gave me only top level files and folders. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You have to recursively call the service to get all the items within the subfolders. I don't there is an option to do it OOTB. Instead, you can always write your custom SharePoint web service to accomplish this.

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/16a2d993-2f5e-4242-8e5a-451a78c064a3
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karthick/archive/2006/03/27/562245.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The issue is in the soap envelope above.