# why I don't get list subfolders despite using RecursiveAll option

Tags: web-services, vba, sharepoint, soap, caml

This is my function why I don't get the subfolders although I'm using recursive ALL option.

I don't even obtain 1-level subfolders I only get the main files and folders, I'm sure I've something wrong in soap request but I can't figure it out.

I've used the same request as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351845/sharepoint-list-getlistitems-webservice-to-return-sub-folder-contents-recursive)

```
Function getResults(url, xmlDoc, spreturnattribute)

    request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:soap1='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>" & _
            " <soap:Header/>" & _
             " <soap:Body>" & _
              "  <soap1:GetListItems>" & _
                "  <soap1:listName>Documents</soap1:listName>" & _
                     "<QueryOptions>" & _
                     "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" & _
                      "<ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/>" & _
                         "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>" & _
                    "</QueryOptions>" & _
                "</soap1:GetListItems>" & _
                  "</soap:Body>" & _
                "</soap:Envelope>"


    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", url, False, Null, Null
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"
        .send request



        xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        xmlDoc.async = False
        xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
        xmlDoc.resolveExternals = False
        xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:namespace='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'"
        xmlDoc.LoadXML (.responseText)

        Dim strQuery: strQuery = ".//z:row"

        Set colItem = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strQuery)

        For Each objItem In colItem
        Debug.Print objItem.Attributes.getNamedItem("ows_LinkFilename").Text
        For Each queryNode In objItem.ChildNodes
          Debug.Print queryNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("ows_LinkFilename").Text
        Next
        Next

    End With

End Function
```

---

### Edit1

Adding reference article

### Edit2

may that due to security issue on the site ? or does setting xmldoc properties cause that?
I'm not very good at VBA but it's an easy script and I wonder why it's not working
and FYI my sharepoint is 2013

Comment: What _do_ you get? Anything at all? Have you looked at the response? What's in `.responseText`?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I've just noticed the 2nd part of ur question , .responseText contains the request text . There're already retrieved data which means that there's no errors in the syntax but may I have to organize it ?!

Comment: I think you mean it contains the response XML from SharePoint? And that the response XML does not contain the subfolders.

Comment: yeah I mean response text of my request (the result ) not the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of trials I've removed all extra unused tags and just checked that link on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd964860(v=office.14).aspx) 
and updated my caml by adding another tag queryoptions as follows which solves my problem:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap:Body>
            <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>listname</listName>
            <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="int">1</Value>
            <rowLimit>0</rowLimit>
            <queryOptions><QueryOptions>   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
            <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"></ViewAttributes></QueryOptions></queryOptions>
            </GetListItems>
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: And what is the result of this? Why is this an answer instead of an edit to your question?

Comment: yeah I should edit it to say that is the answer as I had the list of folders and subfolders in my list

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to specify the "rowLimit" parameter for your query.

You can set a specific number

```
<rowLimit>5000</rowLimit>
```

or get all items with

```
<rowLimit>0</rowLimit>
```

rowLimit is case-sensitive.

Comment: I've added `<rowLimit>0</rowLimit>` inside queryoptions and the results are the same

Comment: Upvote .. After retrieving the actual list I really used that info to get all results as I always having 30 rows only , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Recursive
```

for the scope of ViewAttributes

```
<ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive'/>
```

Comment: I've tried adding soup1 to all tags gradually and the results are the same ,

Comment: there is no results at all :(

Comment: how about the scope ?

Comment: RecursiveAll and Recursive obtain the same results the main files and folders only